# Разложить видео на кадры NET 5

Tags: c#, .net-5

Стоит задача разложить видео на кадры, с возможностью просматривать каждый кадр. Смотрел в сторону ffmpeg и библиотек на его основе. Пишется на net 5. Пытался использовать AForge, Accord.Video.FFMPEG. Но они заточены под dot net framework. Прошу направить в правильное русло, куда копнуть?

Comment: Попробуй FFmpeg.NET. Сам не юзал, но судя по всему это пока самая свежая либа. Странно, что ты на неё не напоролся, зато откопал какие-то старые неподдерживаемые либы.

Answer (score 2):

Ставите nuget пакет OpenCV

```
using OpenCvSharp;

var videoFile = "01.mp4";
var capture = new VideoCapture(videoFile);
var window = new Window("Video Frame by Frame");
var image = new Mat();
var dic_image = new Dictionary<int, Bitmap>()

var i = 0;
while (capture.IsOpened())
{
    capture.Read(image);
    if (image.Empty()) break;
    i++;
    Bitmap frame = BitmapConverter.ToBitmap(image);
    dic_image[i] = frame;
    window.ShowImage(image);
    if (Cv2.WaitKey(1) == 113) // Q
        break;
}
```

После выполнения данного кода в словаре `dic_image` будут кадры из видео с доступом по номеру кадра.
Если `Cv2.WaitKey(1) == 113` вроде как не обязателен, если с ним будут проблемы - можно убрать.

Comment: `'Q'` :) зачем число?